# API POST via Zapier

Tags: rest, zapier, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to trigger a journey in the salesforce marketingcloud by using a REST API POST via Zapier. But Zapier always returns me the error "**You must return a single object or array of objects.**". What am I doing wrong here?

```
var obj = {  
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+inputData.mytoken,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "ContactKey": inputData.data_TransactionID,
    "EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-XXXX",
    "Data": [{
      "TransactionId": inputData.data_TransactionID,
      "DonationAmount": inputData.data_Amount,
      "DonationPurpose": inputData.data_Purpose,  
      "Email": inputData.data_email,
      "SubscriptionToken": inputData.data_SubToken,
      "FirstName": inputData.data_FirstName,
      "LastName": inputData.data_LastName
    }]
  })
}

fetch('https://mc4XXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events', obj)  
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
   })
  .then(function(json) {
    callback(null, json);
   })
  .catch(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing more about the structure of the returned JSON, but I can take a guess.

The error is complaining about the value `json` that is passed into `callback`. Here are a couple of examples of values of that `json` variable:

```js
// cause an error
true
3
undefined
[]
[3]

// no error
{ success: true }
{}
[{ cool: true }]
```

The type of the returned value must be an **object** (`{}`) or an array where every item is an object (`[{}]`).

If you `console.log(json)` before you `callback`, you'll see exactly what you're returning and can figure out how to wrap it in an object. A shot in the dark, but I would guess that `callback(null, {json})` may work.